# Converting double vector to audio DNA sequence for local sequence alignment

Tags: matlab

I need to align two double vectors using local sequence alignment using

```
[Score = swalign(Seq1, Seq2)]
```

But sequences are not strings, so it returns a error. What is the solution for this problem? Can I substitute a unique character for each numerical value? Is there any easy way to locally align two double key vectors in MATLAB?

Comment: You could do what you say and substitute a unique character for each value, but the nature of floating point precision is going to give you a world of problems.  Specifically, there could be floating point values that may look the same, but are classified as different when you look at the finer precision of the number.  Because of this, though two values should be given the same character, you will produce different characters and thus the alignment and score will not be accurate.  The Smith-Waterman local alignment is specifically for DNA sequences. **Why** are you applying this to audio?

Comment: It can be measured similarity of audio DNA. Few researchers have used it. But there are lot of problems and i thought that there may be easy way to do that. No it is not need to convert to unique character. Actually we can't do it and we can use a character for a specific range. Otherwise it becomes so hard. Thus, i want to know an easy way beyond that to apply local sequence alignment. Because, i am doing research on measuring similarity of songs using various methods to find out a proper way.

Comment: We have discusses it. But we are still doing experiments on that. Because, he also hasn't used it before. So if anyone know it, free to explain it.